# how to populate a list dynamically within a dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, dynamic, collections

i want to populate a list in 
`dictionary.timeslot_events.Add(t, new List<int>() { i });` 
but it is giving me exception that more an item with the same key has already added.
i have also tried to populate list with add function `timeslot_events.Add(t, new List<int>() { i });`   but it is giving me exception that the given key was not present in the dictionary.

kindly guide how can i populate it successfully.?  In C++, i used to do it with 
 `map<int, vector<int>>`

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.noevents; i++)
{
    int t = (int)(rg.Next(1, 45));
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    timeslot_events.Add(t, new List<int>() { i });

}
```

Comment: you are generating Random numbers between 1-45, and using them as key. It is possible same number is being generated twice and dictionary must have unique key.

Comment: in c++ i used to do i with map<int, vector<int>>

Comment: you should properly explain what exactly you want? what you want as key and what as value

Comment: 1. Your first and second approaches are the same. You cant basically add an item with same key multiple times to a dictionary, as simple as that. Try `timeslot_events[t] = new List<int>() { i })` for add or update to a dictionary. 2. Show us how variable `rg` is obtained. That could be the key. 3. In case you want to keep adding to inner list, first get the inner list for the key and add to it (if not present, create a new list for that key)

Comment: but i want to add a list of items with same key. how can i do this in c# ?

Comment: rg is of random type. Random rg;

Comment: i want to generate a key and then i want to store  event against that key in the list. then i want to access list of events with same key. i did this with 2-D array. but in 2-D array most of indexes are wasted. that why i want some efficient way for it.

Comment: "given key was not present in the dictionary" - This is the exception when you try to read a key which is not present. It is not possible to get this error message while populating dictionary. Something is wrong. And if you are getting "key present" error, then it's a simple reason that Random can produce duplicates, as mentioned by @Nitin. Otherwise your code is working fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PRErbn

Answer (score 1):

Check if key is already present then add against that key else insert new KeyValue pair like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.noevents; i++)
{
    int t = (int)(rg.Next(1, 45));
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    if (timeslot_events.ContainsKey(t))
    {
        if (timeslot_events[t] == null)
        {
            timeslot_events[t] = new List<int>();
        }
        timeslot_events[t].Add(i);
    }
    else
    {
        timeslot_events.Add(t, new List<int>() { i });
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a bit of LINQ.

```
var query = 
    from n in Enumerable.Range(0, data.noevents)
    group n by rg.Next(1, 45);

foreach (var x in query)
{
    timeslot_events.Add(x.Key, x.ToList());
}
```